# Add jsColor lib to vue component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, components, vuejs2

I am trying to add the simple [jsColor lib](http://jscolor.com/) to my vuejs project, i am working with webpack simple in vueJS.

**So i want to add my script to this component:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3 class="text-center">Paragraph</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fontSize" class="control-label col-md-2">font-size</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input v-model="paragraph.fontSize" type="number" min="1" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img class="changeColor" @click="alignment('left')" width="30" height="30" src="../../assets/left-alignment.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img class="changeColor" @click="alignment('center')" width="30" height="30" src="../../assets/center-alignment.png" />
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img class="changeColor" @click="alignment('right')" width="30" height="30" src="../../assets/right-alignment.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img class="changeColor" @click="alignment('justify')" width="30" height="30" src="../../assets/justify.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <span>{{paragraph.align}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
                Color:
                #<input class="jscolor" v-model="paragraph.color">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="paragraph" class="control-label col-md-2">Text</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea v-model="paragraph.text" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <button @click.prevent="addParagraph()" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add Paragraph</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import jsColor from '../../static/js/jscolor.js';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            paragraph: {
                text: "",
                fontSize: 14,
                key: "Paragraph",
                align: "left",
                color: "000000",
                paragraph: {}
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addParagraph() {
            var paragraph = {
                key: this.paragraph.key,
                text: this.paragraph.text,
                fontSize: this.paragraph.fontSize,
                align: this.paragraph.align,
            }
            this.$store.commit("appendToDocument", paragraph)
            var panelObj = {"section":"paragraph","color":"list-group-item-success","action":"added"};
            this.$store.commit("appendToPanel", panelObj);
        },
        alignment(option) {
            this.paragraph.align = option;
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style>
.margin-above {
    margin-top: 40px
}

.changeColor {
    padding: 5px;
}

.changeColor:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
</style>
```

i already tried to add the import and the require, the only thing that worked was to use the mounted function inside vuejs lifecycle, but the problem is that it just reflects on the first page load, if open the component again the script is not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example component you might be interested in:

https://gist.github.com/niveshsaharan/1c1567d8475b46d6886e387953596e9e

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/6wolq8k4jz

```
<template>
<div class="input-control color-input">
    <input :value="value"
           :id="id"
           class="jscolor-input {hash:true,styleElement:'',onFineChange:'jsColorOnFineChange(this)'}"
           @change="onChange($event.target)"
           @input="onChange($event.target)"
           @focus="showColorPicker"
           @onFineChange="onFineChange"
           ref="color_input"
           maxlength="7"
    />
    <span class="color-value" ref="color_span" @click="showColorPicker"></span>
</div> 
</template>

<script>
import jscolor from './../plugins/jscolor/jscolor.js';
export default {
    name: 'jscolor',
    data(){
        return {
            color: '#000000'
        }
    },
    props: [
        'value',
        'id'
    ],
    methods: {
        onChange(target){
            this.color = target.jscolor.toHEXString();
            this.$refs.color_span.style.backgroundColor = this.color;
            this.$emit('input', this.color);
        },
        onFineChange(e){
            this.color = '#' + e.detail.jscolor;
            this.$refs.color_span.style.backgroundColor = this.color;
            this.$emit('input', this.color);
        },
        showColorPicker(){
            this.$refs.color_input.jscolor.show();
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        window.jscolor.installByClassName('jscolor-input');
        this.$refs.color_span.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
    },
    updated: function () {
        this.$refs.color_span.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
    }
}

window.jsColorOnFineChange = function(thisObj){
    thisObj.valueElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("onFineChange", {detail: {jscolor: thisObj}}));
}
```

Usage:

```
    <jscolor id="colorThemeTextColor" v-model="theme_text_color"></jscolor>
```

Comment: Thanks for developing example code in *codesandbox*.